# Python a string with tabs and integers is different outside print

Tags: python

I'm merging some tab delimited files and the printed output is incorrect but if I access the string in a REPL it looks fine. Here's how it looks:

```
fh=open('out.vcf')
for line in fh:
     i+=1
     if i == 29401:
             print(line)

 
AAEX03025909.1  1068    .   T   C                       0   42  5
```

Then looking at it without print:

```
line
'AAEX03025909.1\t1405\t.\tC\tT\t\t\t\t\t\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t10\t9\n'
```

When I look at out.vcf in less, it looks like the output of print. Why am I getting different outputs? I want the string that is produced without print. Using a comma instead of a tab solves the problem, but I'd like to keep it as tab delimited

Comment: Simple rule: if you want to print something you use `print()`. On the other hand, if you want to inspect a variable for debugging in interactive mode you can just enter the name to get a *technical representation* of the value.

Answer (score 0):

there's always going to be some difference between how data is *represented* and how it's *stored*; practically, the values are stored as binary, but represented depending on the [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) .. in this case, you're seeing `\t` ([ASCII character 9](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/7-ascii/)) represented both ways

`print()` will show the file with its encoding (which you can change), while simply echoing the file will show you the Python `repr()` interpretation

```py
>>> "\t"
'\t'
>>> ord("\t")
9
>>> print("\t")

>>> repr("\t")
"'\\t'"
>>> print(repr("\t"))
'\t'
```